# Where can I get a list of available commands and keys?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I noticed this in a Firefox extension:

```
<command id="Browser:BackOrBackDuplicate" disabled="true"/>
```

and this in the preferences:

```
browser.gesture.swipe.left;  Browser:BackOrBackDuplicate
```

I assume from this that `Browser:BackOrBackDuplicate` is a function of Firefox.

I also noticed this in the extension:

```
<key id="key_cut" disabled="true"/>
```

Where can I get a list of these methods and keys by name and what they do?  I tried searching for it, but I don't know what keywords to use to get the right results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These commands and keys aren't documented for a reason - they are used internally by the browser and can change any time without prior notice. Extensions shouldn't touch them without a **very** good reason.

That said, if you *really* want to mess with them, you can find all of them defined in [browser-sets.inc](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc) (this file becomes part of `browser.xul` when Firefox is compiled). Most of the commands are implemented in [browser.js](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js), some are not - you can [search the code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) to find their implementation. You can also use [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) extension to inspect the browser window at runtime.

Comment: browser-sets.inc now lives at https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc

Comment: @azrdev: And DOM Inspector is gone, this kind of functionality is now available in the built-in Developer Tools. Not that it matters, given that browser extensions no longer have this kind of access.